# Why is backdrop-filter only working when I manually modify the original CSS file of an Apex Theme in the Browser Inspector?

Tags: css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

*Original Question: Is there a way to forcefully add a new CSS property to an Apex Universal Theme element?*

First of all, I know this is just a stylistic feature, but it could also apply to usability features and I want to think there's a workaround to it (or that I just haven't tried everything possible).
I'm making a web app using Oracle Apex 5.1.4. The app is styled with the built-in **Universal Theme 42.** I'm trying to give a custom style to the login page (generated by Apex upon creation of the application), specifically the Login content, through it's class `t-Login-region`. I have been able to change already existing properties (such as `background-color`, `border-radius`, etc.) and some new ones (such as `filter`).

I've ran into an issue where I'm trying to apply `backdrop-filter` to the Login region so it blurs the background below it. I tried adding the property from the browser inspector to test it live without altering the CSS, then from the *Theme Roller,* and lastly from the *Page Designer* (Inline CSS). None of these worked... by themselves.

[Here's how it looks currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMerH.png)

After a while of meddling through the inspector I noticed this block in the **original CSS file** of the page's theme (Core.min.css?v=5.1.4.00.08) that applies style to the `t-Login-region` class:

```
.t-Login-region {
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 32px
}
```

I added a semicolon to the last line and `backdrop-filter` [is now working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5AO2.png). Now I noticed the effect starts working **ONLY** when I make any live changes to that CSS file via the Browser Inspector. Also, this is only happening with `backdrop-filter`. I changed it to `filter` and it works just fine, so I can effectively add new properties, it's just precisely the one I'm trying to add that doesn't work...

Anyways, here's my custom CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 50%, white 50%);
}

.t-Login-region {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify your application's theme CSS file by shared components -> themes page. There, you need to find the filename of your current theme's style file. Then, search on this page for this file name (usually a name like 12345567.css) and then you can make modifications.

EDIT:
When you click to the filename, not the download button, you should be able to edit it on a built-in editor:
[image: CSS file]

[image: CSS edit]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried doing that, but the Apex interface only gives me an option to download these files, where I can then modify them with any text editor but have no way of uploading them again to use them as main theme css files. I just edited my question to add some important context; backdrop-filter is the only property that I can't get to work and it only applies when I manually change anything from the original CSS code in the inspector. Perhaps you have any idea about that behavior?

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to edit those files and upload them now (though not the same way as you did, because I'm on Apex 5.1 and the UI is slightly different, there's no built-in editor). Sadly, the problem remains that the backdrop-filter only starts working as soon as I make any changes to the "Core.min.css?v=5.1.4.00.08" file (the global and original theme's CSS file) via the browser's inspector. It's the only CSS property behaving this way

Comment: did you try to use !important in your CSS rule?

Comment: Yes, already tried that. I have even tried dynamically styling the element through Javascript after the page loads, no luck there. It seems like it's more of an issue with the backdrop-filter property itself